# Bootstrap carousel controls not working with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, bootstrap-4, carousel, ejs

Creating a sailing website, in the testimonials part the left and right controls and indicators are not responding. Is this because I have not included or called the function in the app.js or am I missing some jQuery? (Using .ejs)

I have looked into slick-carousel-npm and other packages, in simple HTML and CSS form the code isnt working also.

```
<section class="colouredSection">
  <div id="sectionContainer">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <h2 class="testimonial-text">"What a beautiful day! Our skipper was amazing and even taught us how to sail a bit. I would
              definitely recommend and repeat in the future!!! A perfect way to spend an afternoon in Barcelona."</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">"What a beautiful day! Our skipper was amazing and even taught us how to sail a bit. I would
            definitely recommend and repeat in the future!!! A perfect way to spend an afternoon in Barcelona."</h2>
      </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">"What a beautiful day! Our skipper was amazing and even taught us how to sail a bit. I would
            definitely recommend and repeat in the future!!! A perfect way to spend an afternoon in Barcelona."</h2>
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
<!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,800,800i|Special+Elite|Playfair+Display:400i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In the app.get("/", .. I have made no reference to the carousel. There is no responsiveness when I expect it to move through the slides of sailing trip reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `utils.js` or `bootstrap.js` somewhere in your `<body>` tags.

> Lastly, if you’re building our JavaScript from source, it requires util.js.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

> All Bootstrap’s JavaScript files depend on util.js and it has to be included alongside the other JavaScript files. If you’re using the compiled (or minified) bootstrap.js, there is no need to include this—it’s already there.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#util

Comment: To clarify the css and bootstrap links shown are placed in the <head> of the page. Does this mean that the bootstrap cdn does not include util.js? I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: The Bootstrap CSS and Bootstrap JS are separate. The JS file should be place in a script tag at the very bottom of your <body> tag.

Comment: Thank you! Both Bootstrap CSS and Bootstrap JS were in place, it was causing a problem because their versions didn´t match! All sorted